# ImportError: No module named localflavor.br.br_states

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.6b and python 2.7.5 and I get this import error,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.localflavor.br.br_states import STATE_CHOICES
class Contato(models.Model):
    SEXO_CHOICES = (
        (u'masculino', u'Masculino'),
        (u'feminino', u'Feminino'),
    )
    ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES = (
        (u'solteiro', u'Solteiro'),
        (u'casado', u'Casado'),
        (u'divorciado', u'Divorciado'),
        (u'viuvo', u'Viúvo'),
    )
    contato_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contato_nome = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name='Nome')
    contato_nascimento = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')
    contato_sexo = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEXO_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexo')
    contato_estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES, verbose_name='Estado Civil')
    contato_foto = models.ImageField(max_length=255, blank=True, upload_to='contato/%Y', verbose_name='Foto')
    contato_email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Email')
    contato_site = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Site')
    contato_observacoes = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Observações')
    contato_favorito = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Favorito')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.contato_nome
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'contato'
        verbose_name = 'Contato'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contatos'
        ordering = ['contato_nome']
class Endereco(models.Model):
    TIPO_LOGRADOURO_CHOICES = (
        (u'rua', u'Rua'),
        (u'avenida', u'Avenida'),
        (u'travessa', u'Travessa'),
    )
    endereco_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contato = models.ForeignKey(Contato)
    endereco_tipo_logradouro = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TIPO_LOGRADOURO_CHOICES, verbose_name='Tipo Logradouro')
    endereco_logradouro = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Logradouro')
    endereco_numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Número')
    endereco_complemento = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, verbose_name='Complemento')
    endereco_bairro = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Bairro')
    endereco_cidade = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Cidade')
    endereco_estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Estado')
    endereco_cep = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, verbose_name='CEP')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s, %s, %s, %s - %s' % (self.endereco_tipo_logradouro, self.endereco_logradouro, self.endereco_numero, self.endereco_bairro, self.endereco_cidade, self.endereco_estado)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'endereco'
        verbose_name = 'Endereço'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Endereços'
        ordering = ['endereco_tipo_logradouro']
class Telefone(models.Model):
    TELEFONE_TIPO_CHOICES = (
        (u'residencial', u'Residencial'),
        (u'celular', u'Celular'),
        (u'comercial', u'Comercial'),
    )
    telefone_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contato = models.ForeignKey(Contato)
    telefone_tipo = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TELEFONE_TIPO_CHOICES, verbose_name='Tipo')
    telefone_numero = models.CharField(max_length=135, verbose_name='Número')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.telefone_numero
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'telefone'
```

Import Error:

```
python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/localuser/agenda/contato/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.localflavor.br.br_states import STATE_CHOICES
ImportError: No module named localflavor.br.br_states
```

I've tried create an application using django 1.6.2, but I found a problem with 'import' Looking for the documentation, but I don't found nothin'.
For now I'm going to not use django helpers for my address model but I'm not sure what's causing this import exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It moved:

Change your app’s import statements to reference the new package.

For example, change this:

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.fr.forms import FRPhoneNumberField
```

...to this:

```
from localflavor.fr.forms import FRPhoneNumberField
```

See the docs at: http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.6.x/topics/localflavor.html#how-to-migrate

Comment: If this fixes your problem you can check it for me

Comment: It does not work! the problem 'ImportError: No module named localflavor.br.br_states' still there. I was looking in the docs about django 1.6, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you do import localflavor  just to see if it is there?

Comment: I founded a solution, just addicted a list of STATE_CHOICES, docs help, thank you joel.